# After Vue.delete or $delete UI is not updating

Tags: vue.js

this is my first question on stackoverflow. 
So, I try to delete a item from array, I see, that in Vue Dev Tools it was deleted, but UI not updating. 
I become this array as response from Laravel API and send dynamic to Vue Component like this

```
...
<admin-panel :jurisdictions="{{ $jurisdictions }}"></admin-panel>
...
```

then in my AdminComponent I redirect to AdminHomeComponent with props like this

```
<template>
    <router-view :jurisdictions="jurisdictions"></router-view>
</template>
...
props: ['jurisdictions'],
...
created() {
   this.$router.push({ name: "AdminHomeComponent" }).catch(err => {});
},
...
```

In AdminHomeComponent I have props too and router link to another component JurisdictionsComponent like this

```
<template>
...
  <router-link :to="{name: 'JurisdictionsComponent'}"> Jurisdictions</router-link>
...
</template>
<script>
...
   props: ["jurisdictions"]
...
</script>
```

And then will fun, wenn in JurisdictionsComponent I add a new one, or editing old one it works, there are reactive, but if I try to delete one, it still be reactive and I see this in Vue Dev Tools, but I cann't unterstand, why UI not updating..

JurisdictionsComponent

```
<template>
    <div class="w-100">
        <div id="jurisdictionsContainer" ref="jurisdictionsContainer">
                <div class="panel-heading d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Jurisdictions</h3>
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        <button @click.prevent="$modal.show('create-edit-jurisdiction', {'action' : 'create'})">
                            <i class="fas fa-plus-square"/> Create new
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <table class="table table-hover mt-2 rounded" id="jurisdictions-table">
                    <thead class="thead-dark ">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="jurisdictions-table-body">
```

here I make v-for

```
                    <tr v-if="jurisdictions !== null" v-for="(jurisdiction, index) in this.jurisdictions" v-bind:key="jurisdiction.id"
                        class="result clickable-row"
                        @click="show($event, jurisdiction)">
                        <td class="title">
                            {{ jurisdiction.title }}
                        </td>
                        <td class="position-relative">
                            <button @click="$modal.show('create-edit-jurisdiction', {'jurisdiction': jurisdiction, 'index': index, 'action' : 'edit'})">
                                <div class="not-clickable">Edit</div>
```

here a show a delete modal window, use can deside delete or not, my code from ModalDeleteComponent see below

```
                            </button>
    <button @click="$modal.show('delete-jurisdiction', {'jurisdiction': jurisdiction, 'index': index})">
                                <div class="not-clickable">Delete</div>
                                <i class="fas fa-trash-alt not-clickable"/>
                            </button>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                <delete-jurisdiction @onDeleted="onClickDelete"/>
                <create-edit-jurisdiction @create="onClickCreate" @edit="onClickEdit":errors="this.errors.createEdit"/>
            </div>
    </div>

</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: "JurisdictionsComponent",
        props: ["jurisdictions"],
        data() {
            return {
                isAllSelected: false,
                errors: {
                    createEdit: {},
                    addEvent: {}
                },
            }
        },
        methods: {
            /**
             * Create a new jurisdiction
             *
             * @param data form
             */
            onClickCreate(data) {
                axios.post("/admin-dashboard/jurisdictions", data.form)
                .then(response => {
                    response.data.image === undefined ? response.data.image = null : response.data.image;
                    response.data.selected = false;
                    this.jurisdictions.push(response.data);
                    this.$modal.hide("create-edit-jurisdiction");
                    this.errors.createEdit = {}
                })
                .catch(errors => {
                    this.errors.createEdit = errors.response.data.errors;
                });
```

Here a try to delete jurisdiction, it deletes from database, from props in Vue Dev Tools but not from UI

```
            /**
             * Delete jurisdiction request
             *
             * @param index
             */
            onClickDelete(index) {
                axios.delete("/admin-dashboard/jurisdictions/" + this.jurisdictions[index].id)
                    .then(() => {
                        this.$delete(this.jurisdictions, index);
                        this.$modal.hide("delete-jurisdiction");
                    })
                    .catch(errors => {
                        console.log(errors)
                    });
            },
            /**
             * Edit a jurisdiction
             *
             * @param data form
             */
            onClickEdit(data) {
                axios.patch(this.jurisdictions[data.index].path, data.form)
                .then(response => {
                    this.$set(this.jurisdictions, data.index, response.data);
                    this.$modal.hide("create-edit-jurisdiction");
                    this.errors.createEdit = {}
                })
                .catch(errors => {
                    this.errors.createEdit = errors.response.data.errors;
                })
            },
    }
</script>
```

ModalDeleteComponent

```
<template>
    <modal name="delete-jurisdiction" @before-open="beforeOpen" height="200" @before-close="beforeClose">
        <div class="h-100">
            <div v-if="jurisdiction !== null" class="p-4 mt-2">
                <h3>Do you want really delete
                    <a :href="'/admin-dashboard/jurisdictions/'+jurisdiction.id"><strong>{{ jurisdiction.title }}</strong></a>
                    <span v-if="jurisdiction.events.length > 0">
                            with {{ jurisdiction.events.length }} {{ jurisdiction.events.length === 1 ? 'event' : "events"}}
                    </span>?
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="bg-dark d-flex justify-content-around p-2 position-absolute w-100" style="bottom: 0">
                <button class="btn btn-danger" @click="submitDelete">Delete</button>
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" @click="$modal.hide('delete-jurisdiction')">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </modal>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "ModalDeleteJurisdictionComponent",
        data() {
            return {
                jurisdiction: null,
                index: ""
            }
        },
        methods: {
            submitDelete() {
                this.$emit('onDeleted', this.index);
            },
            beforeOpen (event) {
                this.jurisdiction = event.params.jurisdiction;
                this.index = event.params.index;
            },
            beforeClose(event) {
                this.jurisdiction = null;
                this.index = "";
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I know, my question is too long, but if anyone tries to answer this, I will very happy)) 
I'm open to any contra questions. Sorry for my English

Comment: welcome to SO. you should narrow down your problem and the code a lot, otherwise no one is going to help you. However, jurisdictions is coming from props and if you want to update it together with the UI, it should be part of data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You mean a part of `data() {return {jurisdictions: this.jurisdictions }}` I have tried, but Vue says: "The data property "jurisdictions" is already declared as a prop. Use prop default value instead". And I'm surprising, that when I editing or adding UI updates

Comment: glad it helped. still posted a more detailed answer, which I forgot to submit earlier.

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks [oshell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2661301/oshell) for a tipp. Ich have renamed in jurisdictions to dataJurisdictions and init in `created() {this.dataJurisdictions = this.jurisdictions}` as well. First of all I want to avoid duplication of data in components and work only with `props`, but nevertheless it works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You are adding to `jurisdictions`, which is a prop.

```
this.jurisdictions.push(response.data);
```

However, you should either update the prop in the parent component, to trigger a prop change and re-render or assign the prop to the components data as initial value and then update data.

Changing prop in parent component can be done using `$emit` or by using `Vuex`.

Assigning data locally just needs a different value name.

```
this.localJurisdictions = this.jurisdictions
```

And for updating then use this new data value. (Use accordingly in template.)

```
this.localJurisdictions.push(response.data);
```